# AngularJS: obtain message reply before continue an action

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple controller method that does some action (it controls header of my page). I would like, however, to send a message and confirm that other controllers (such as form controllers on page main body) permit that action.

What I would like to do, is:

- from the first controller, send a message "BeforeAction"
- in another controller, catch that message, generate a reply that might be context-dependent and somehow deliver that reply to first contoller.
- based on reply, either continue my action or drop it.
- if no listeners to the message Before Action exist, I would like action to continue seamlessly.

How this can be arranged in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sharing data between controllers you have 2 options. The better one is probably to create a shared service and inject it into both controllers. In this service you could have a message variable. Controller1 could set the message. Controller2 could have a $watch on the message and act appropriatly when the message value changes.

The other option is to use a custom event. If you use $rootScope.$emit(message) in Controller1 this will travel down the scope chain where you can use $scope.$on(message) to catch it.

I think that for you the service would work better. It woyuld allow you to hold a register of listeners that both controllers could access. For example if Controller2 sets a watch on the message variable save this fact to a register variable. In Controller1 beforeAction you can first check the register. If it's empty proceed, otherwise change the value of the message variable